# linux vs mac pathname works diffferently... I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, linux, django, subprocess, pipeline

I have successfully initiated a unix command `samtools view -h [path_to_file_of_interest]`, using a subpocess command (Popen) on my mac computer- this is in order to develop a pipeline process. This was done in a django environment called from the views.py file.

Tree

```
    pipe
      -myproject
         -myapp
            -views.py
```

I then had to re-develop the project on a linux computer which has the server that will ultimately be used to publish the django site. So I emailed the zip file to myself and downloaded the pipe directory on the linux machine.

Problem: the command chain works fine up until the subprocess call on `samtools view -h [path_to_file_of_interest]`.

As I am using a relative path command, I assumed that there would not be an issue with paths:

```
1         for file in os.listdir(settings.MEDIA_ROOT):
2             if file.endswith(".bam"):
3               bamfile = file
4
5               path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, bamfile) #path not working
6               print "testing",path #DEBUG
7               print "step-1" #DEBUG
8               print "step-2" #DEBUG
9               os.system("module load samtools/1.3") 
10              print "step-3" #DEBUG
11              print "step-4 - creating reads.sam" #DEBUG
12              with open("reads.sam", "w") as output:
13                  print 'start' #DEBUG
14                  a = subprocess.Popen(["samtools", "view", "-h", path], stdout=out)
16                  print 'middle'#DEBUG
17                  a.communicate()[0]
```

As mentioned above this process works fine on a mac but in the linux environment when running the site, the pipeline fails at the subprocess stage, returning the error:

```
I/O operation on closed file
```

On lines commented as "DEBUG" I am just testing where the process is failing (consistently on line 14).

On line 9, I load the module for the downloaded `samtools` (although I do not have to do this on a mac).

On line 14, I have also tried to use `os.systems` in the place of `Popen` (and use an absolute path to the file of interest) but that returns the error:

```
'file' object is not callable
```

not sure if this error stems from the variable 'file' set in a for loop on line 1 or if it is just another path issue.

Using an absolute path with `Popen` returns the same error- "I/O...." mentioned above.

Either way  the systems between mac and linux are handling the commands/ variables differently and I'm hoping someone can help me out....

Comment: Have you tried using `os.path.abspath`?

Comment: yeah tried that but it returns: "'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'abspath'" eventhough I have imported 'sys' and 'os'... I get a similar error when I include 'stdout=out.PIPE' as my standard output eventhough I have imported 'subprocess'. When I try 'from subprocess/sys/os import ....' it gives error for not importing subprocess/sys/os....